# Database user with global privileges does not have access to newly created database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database user `create_db_user` to which I have granted all privileges on databases with a certain prefix:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  'myprefix\_%'.* TO  'create_db_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

I have another database user account `standard_user` to which I grant `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` privileges.

The global user executes a SQL statement that creates a new database: `myprefix_new_db`. It appears to do so without any problems (at least no exceptions are thrown at that point). When, however, it then tries to grant SIUD privileges to the standard account for that newly created database, the following exception is thrown:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'create_db_user'@'localhost' to database 'myprefix_new_db' @ #0`

So, on the surface at least, it appears that my global user account has enough privileges to create a database, but not enough to interact with it.

The exact code flow is as follows:

```
$create_db_user->query(" SET SQL_MODE = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' ");
$create_db_user->execute();

$stmt = ' CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $myprefix_new_db . ' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; ';
$stmt.= ' USE ' . $myprefix_new_db . ';';
$stmt.= $sql_stmt;

$create_db_user->query($stmt);
$create_db_user->execute();

// with or without grant option
$create_db_user->query(" GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  {$myprefix_new_db}.* TO 'create_db_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; ");
$create_db_user->execute();

$sql = " GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `{$myprefix_new_db}`.* TO 'standard_user'@'localhost' ";
$create_db_user->query($sql);
$create_db_user->execute();
```

My question is: what must I do to ensure that my `create_db_user` account has sufficient privileges to do whatever it wants to *dynamically* created databases? Or, what must I do to ensure that once a database is created, that it is included under the scope of the global user?

EDIT: I have admin-level cPanel and WHM access.

Comment: Side note: executing `SET SQL_MODE = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'` is dangerous because you disable other sql_modes within your session.. Better is to use `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode. ', NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO');` instead this will keep other sql_modes also active.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ah! Thank you!

Comment: in the PHP code there isn't a `WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was taking it out and putting it back in, while trying things. An error is still thrown either way...

Comment: You should ofcource also give the current PHP MySQL user also `WITH GRANT OPTION` on that newly created database other wise it can't grant privileges to other users.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have updated the code to reflect the current status. Access is denied once I try to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ...`.

Comment: Why is the host showing `#0`? in `'myprefix_new_db' @ #0`

Comment: 1. What is `$sql_stmt`, as appended to `$stmt` after the `CREATE ...` and `USE ...` lines? 2. You have cPanel; what privileges does the `create_db_user` currently have?

Comment: You say no exceptions are thrown; how about warnings?  If you're using PDO, have you set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?  That will make sure that errors aren't "silently" discarded.

Comment: @hunteke the `create_db_user` has (currently) all privileges. I am also currently displaying all errors and notices.

Comment: @Eamonn I suggest your use your library's "Exception" mode and do some version of an image paste/confirmation here, because the details aren't aligning.  If `create_db_user` has all privileges, the setup and code you have works (which I confirmed on a quick local setup).

Comment: @hunteke This works on my local WAMP setup as well - it just doesn't on the live server. I'm wondering really if there is some setting somewhere that is interfering.

Comment: what user account are you using when creating the database and granting permission to create_db_user?

Comment: The first `GRANT` seems to be trying to grant `ALL` to "self" (i.e. the user currently logged). First I am not sure this is allowed at all, second this user already has those privileges as per your initial conditions. Or else I totally misread you.

Comment: The foremost reason would be the server woudn't allowing you to `Grant  access` through query but rather manually from `Cpanel's` dashboard. Did you ask your service provider about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you are trying to get create_db_user to grant himself all privileges along with the with grant option on a database. I am not sure it should be allowed.

Could you grant the privileges to create_db_user from another user who has the proper WITH GRANT privileges, through a trigger for instance ?

Good luck :-)

Comment: So - remove GRANT from the `create_db_user`, and use that simply to create databases, but have a third account (e.g. `permissions_db_user`) just for assigning permissions?

Comment: I'd go with a privileged user (e.g. permissions_db_user) granting privileges after database creation to create_db_user.

Answer (score 2):

Every database has different and separate permission rules. When a new database created only some accounts are add by default. Each time a new database created old permissions should be extracted,filtered, (possible edited) and copied into new database.

If new and old database has different in these information_schema tables;

You can copy these and paste them into the new database via a account with schema privileges.(however it may require copying/filtering/editing)

- SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
- USER_PRIVILEGES

Access permissions will be different. Can you verify these tables have required rows in them ?

If massive amount of databases created dynamically, in order to avoid copying/filtering/editing. Create a base default database and use import/export scripts to clone it with your variables.

Just to highlight: Granting permission on data and granting permission on users requires different level of access which u are aware of.

An other caution please: Try to create a new connection and run GRANT on that connection which is connected to the new DB. If you are using some preset platform creating a DB and GRANTING from outside (even for a global user) might be blocked and these statements can get ignored silently.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing flushing privileges after grant privileges

```
Flush privileges;
```

Comment: It is my understanding that you do not need to flush privileges after a `GRANT` statement. I did have it in there, but I took it out after reading up on my problem.

Comment: ok, did you try this using some other sql client for same sequence? Which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: I suggest you try flush privileges again, if there is no syntax error than it has to be flush privileges. Also, try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.